# JSON data not loading

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am trying to load some data from an API into html. But it is not returning anything. My code is below. I have inspected it with developer tools but no errors. Kindly help please.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

            $.getJSON('http://uapi.staging.simplestream.com//tvplayer/channels/programmes/2013-09-01/referer/tvplayer?format=json',function(data){
                $('#content').empty();
                $.each(data, function(entryIndex, entry){
                    var html = '<div class="data">';                      
                    html += '<div class="title">' + entry['title'] + '</h3>';
                    html += '<div class="shortDesc">' + entry['synopsis'] + '</div>';                   
                    html += '<div class="duration">' + entry['duration'] + '</div>';                                        
                    $('#content').append(html);
                });                        
            });
            return false;

    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="content" style="width:500px; height:800px;">
<div class="ellipsis title"></div>
<div class="ellipsis shortDesc"></div>
<div class="duration"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the API on the same domain as your code? Because the first thing that comes to mind is that you're attempting a cross-domain request which you can't do unless the request is JSONP and the server hosting the API accepts JSONP.

Comment: That server responds with plain JSON as far as I can tell.

Comment: What happens when you navigate to the request in your browser's address bar: `http://uapi.staging.simplestream.com/tvplayer/channels/programmes/2013-09-01/referer/tvplayer?format=json`. I get a valid response `{
error: "Access denied '<ip-address>' is not in the UK, Ireland, Isle Of Man or Jersey."
}`.